# Processing a large xml file with perl

Tags: xml, perl, sax, libxml2

I have an XML file which is about 200MB in size, i wish to extract selected information on a line by line bases.

I have written a script with perl using the module XML::LibXML to parse the file contents in and then loop the contents and extract the information line by line. This is ineffective as it reads in the whole file to memory, but I like LibXML as I can use the XPath locations of the information i require.

Can I get suggestions for ways to make my code more effective.

Through searching i have been made aware of XML::SAX and XML::LibXML::SAX but i cannot find documentation which explains the usage and they don't seem to include any type of XPath addressing structure.

Comment: You might try XML::Twig (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3A%3ATwig)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you considered the [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) module, which is much more efficient for large file processing, as it states in the [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) module description:

*NAME*

> XML::Twig - A perl module for
> processing **huge XML documents** in
> tree mode.

*SYNOPSIS*

> ...
>
> It allows minimal resource (CPU and
> memory) usage by building the tree
> only for the parts of the documents
> that need actual processing, through
> the use of the twig_roots and
> twig_print_outside_roots options.
>
> ...

Comment: Thank you for pointed me in this direction, So far my investigation is showing positive results

Answer (score 1):

I had some luck with `XML::Twig` but ended up with [XML::LibXML::Reader](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Reader.pod) which is much faster... You may also check `XML::LibXML::Pattern` if you need to use XPath.